# Remove "Siri & Search" from my preferences pane?

Tags: ios

My app is essentially a calculator so I'm not sure how it would integrate with Siri. When you make a preferences pane by including the bundle in Xcode, it now includes a section for "Siri & Search". Is there a way to remove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, as of iOS 12, there is **no way** to remove that section from the app settings, it's even included when there are no custom preferences added for the app. It even stays there if you turn off Siri completely.

Comment: Yikes! Well ok, at least I won't keep Googling it!

Comment: ...well, I guess I could to my own prefs internal, but that seems to be too much work just to remove this.

Comment: It's very annoying  that it takes space at the top of the screen and my options are placed below this permission.